# jquery validation form (codeigniter)

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

Js:

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#username').change(function(){
                var username = $('#username').val();
                $('#usernamemsg').html('<img src="<?php echo base_url()?>images/ajax_loader.gif"/> Checking');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url()?>user/username_validation",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: "username="+username,                     
                    success: function(data){
                        if(data.valid){
                            $('#usernamemsg').html(data.msg);
                        }else{
                            $('#usernamemsg').html(data.msg);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Views:

```
<form id="add" method="post" action="">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Username</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
                <div id="usernamemsg"></div></td></tr>      
            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td><input type="password" id="password" name="password" /></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="add" value="OK" id="submit" /></td></tr>
            </table></form>
```

Controller:

```
        public function index(){
            $data['title']          = 'Register';
            $data['template']       = 'outside/validation/validation';
            $this->load->view('templates/home_template',$data);

        $add = $this->input->post('add');
        if($add){
            $data                = array(
            'username'           => trim($this->input->post('username')),
            'password'           => trim($this->input->post('password')));
            $this->data_mod->insert('user',$data);
            redirect('registration/welcome');
        }
    }   
public function username_validation(){
        $user = $this->data_mod->validation('user',array('username' => $this->input->post('username')));                        
        if($user >= 1){
            $msg = array(
            'valid' => false,
            'msg'   => 'Username is already taken');
        }else{
            $msg = array(
            'valid' => true,
            'msg'   => 'Username is available');
        }
        echo json_encode($msg);
    }
```

*** I'm trying to learn English, so i speak not well.

When i press submit, the form does not notify the username field and it submit to server althought the code of js is working correct when i'm typing a username.

Could someone help me?

Comment: you mean even though the username is not valid, the form keep collect the username and insert it to db?

Comment: Did you mean if the input is empty then you want to be notified ?

Comment: @bondythegreat yes! that is my problem.


Sheikh Heera 
if i add that condition in js, when i submit, it does not validate the field and insert to database.

Answer (score 1):

Then try this inside your `js`

```
var username = $('#username').val();
if($.trim(username).length==0)
{
    alert('Please enter user name !');
    return false;
}
```

Just before following line

```
$('#usernamemsg').html('<img src="<?php echo base_url()?>images/ajax_loader.gif"/> Checking');
```

and also in your `success` callback  replace

```
if(data.valid){
    $('#usernamemsg').html(data.msg);
}else{
    $('#usernamemsg').html(data.msg);
}
```

with

```
$('#usernamemsg').html(data.msg);
```